# R: eval parse function call not accessing correct environments

Tags: r, function, environment-variables

I'm trying to read a function call as a string and evaluate this function within another function. I'm using eval(parse(text = )) to evaluate the string. The function I'm calling in the string doesn't seem to have access to the environment in which it is nested. In the code below, my "isgreater" function finds the object y, defined in the global environment, but can't find the object x, defined within the function. Does anybody know why, and how to get around this? I have already tried adding the argument envir = .GlobalEnv to both of my evals, to no avail.

```
str <- "isgreater(y)"

isgreater <- function(y) {
  return(eval(y > x))
}

y <- 4

test <- function() {
  x <- 3
  return(eval(parse(text = str)))
}

test()
```

Error:

```
Error in eval(y > x) : object 'x' not found
```

Comment: This just isn't going to work. R uses lexical scoping which means it looks for free variables in the environment where a function is **defined**, not where it's called. Not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish but eval/parse is rarely ever a good design strategy. Why not just make `x` a parameter to `is.greater`?

Comment: @MrFlick You're right. I made this change in my code and it works. However I'm still getting the same error in my actual use case. I'll try to figure out why and then update my question.

Comment: Ari, many "best practices" (in R and other languages) recommend "explicit" over "clever conveniences", especially in places where variable-scope and namespace-search are either complicated or at least misunderstood. There's a difference in my head between "clever (convenient)" and "clever (elegant)", where the latter is *good*, and the former will almost always add corner-cases that trigger *very obscure bugs/messages* requiring significant debugging efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MrFlick and @r2evans for their useful and thought-provoking comments. As far as a solution, I've found that this code works. x must be passed into the function and cannot be a default value. In the code below, my function generates a list of results with the x variable being changed within the function. If anyone knows why this is, I would love to know.

```
str <- "isgreater(y, x)"

isgreater <- function(y, x) {
   return(eval(y > x))
}

y <- 50

test <- function() {
  list <- list()
  for(i in 1:100) {
    x <- i
    bool <- eval(parse(text = str))
    list <- append(list, bool)
  }
  return(list)
}

test()
```

After considering the points made by @r2evans, I have elected to change my approach to the problem so that I do not arrive at this string-parsing step. Thanks a lot, everyone.

Comment: Is it your intent to answer your own question or ask a new one? New questions should not be written as answers to other questions. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. Also note that this method of creating a list is troublesome: see [Circle 2 in the R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I offer the following code, not as a solution, but rather as an insight into how R "works". The code does things that are quite dangerous and should only be examined for its demonstration of how to assert a value for x. Unfortunately, that assertion does destroy the `x`-value of `3` inside the `isgreater`-function:

```
str <- "isgreater(y)"

isgreater <- function(y) {
  return(eval( y > x ))
}

y <- 4

test <- function() {
  environment(isgreater)$x <- 5
  return(eval(parse(text = str) ))
}

test()
#[1] FALSE
```

The `environment<-` function is used in the R6 programming paradigm. Take a look at `?R6` if you are interested in working with a more object-oriented set of structures and syntax. (I will note that when I first ran your code, there was an object named `x` in my workspace and some of my efforts were able to succeed to the extent of not throwing an error, but they were finding that length-10000 vector and filling up my console with logical results until I escaped the console. Yet another argument for passing both x and y to `isgreater`.)